# How currying works

Tags: scala

I have following function with parameter lists:

```
def foo(a:Int, b:Int)(x:Int)(y:Int) = a * b + x - y
```

when I put the command on the relp

```
foo _
```

it shows me

```
res5: (Int, Int) => Int => (Int => Int) = <function2>
```

The first part expects two int parameters and then I do not know anymore how to read continue.
I can use the function like

```
foo(5,5)(10)(10)
```

but I do not know how to read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, A => B is the type of an anonymous function that, when given an argument of
type A, returns a value of type B.
Now, the type
`(Int, Int) => Int => (Int => Int)`
might look less confusing when you add some parenthesis:

`(Int, Int) => (Int => (Int => Int))`

As a start, just break it down to

`(Int, Int) => (… => …)`

i.e. a function that, given two `Int`, returns another function. The
function that is returned has type

`(Int => (Int => Int))`

i.e. a function that, given an Int, returns another function that, given an Int,
returns an Int.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. (Int, Int) => Int => (Int => Int) means that 2 first steps returns a function that will take some arguments. For example:

```
(Int, Int) => Function that return
  (Int) => Function that return
    (Int) => Int
```

Why is it useful? Because when you have a function that take a function as parameter in of it's arguments list you can omit parentheses and use curly braces.

```
def someFunStuff(fun: Int)(stuff: Int => Int) = {
  fun*stuff(fun)
}

someFunStuff(2) { x =>
  //Do some fun stuff
  x * 2 / x
}
```

If you want to know a little bit more, please read Chapter 9.4 programming in Scala second edition.